# Using WPF to Generate Images in a WCF service

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, image, iis

I am generating WPF .png images in my WCF service. All works well for a while but eventually I get this error:

```
    System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' threw an exception. --->
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(WNDCLASSEX_D wc_d)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.EnsureResourceChangeListener()
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindResourceInternal(Object key, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean
mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetThemeStyle(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateThemeStyleProperty()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.TryFireInitialized()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EndInit()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.InitializationGuard(XamlType
xamlType, Object obj, Boolean begin)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader
xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
resourceLocator)
```

I have never been able to create this error locally, only on my hosts web server. I have tried several fixes and workarounds including:

[ASP.NET Throws Win32Exception when creating BitmapImage, cannot find file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995588/asp-net-throws-win32exception-when-creating-bitmapimage-cannot-find-file-specif)
http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Generating_images_using_WPF_on_the_Server.aspx

However, I have yet to find a method which works. Can someone please post some code that does not throw this error or at least can work around it somehow. This is what my service does:

```
// Only one copy of the dispatcher (I have tried creating a new one each time too).
private BackgroundStaDispatcher dispatcher = new BackgroundStaDispatcher();
public Stream GetImage()
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/png";
    Stream stream = null;
    this.dispatcher.Invoke(
        () =>
        {
            UserControl userControl = new UserControl()
            {
                DataContext = "Hello World"
            };
            // Use PngBitmapEncoder to convert the control to a bitmap.
            stream = userControl.ToPng(173, 173);
        });
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: I'm taking a guess, but I think it might have something to do with using a UserControl from the web server. I'm thinking that you can't instantiate a UserControl from a web application and that is why you are getting the error. The local test setup probably has permission to create UserControls but the web likely doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else having this issue. I was creating a new UserControl each time, setting its DataContext and converting it to PNG. Instead, just create the UserControl once at the beginning and keep hold of it and reuse it.